# remove spaces added with using as.formula

Tags: r

I create a formula from text, but the resulting formula contains unwanted spaces. Is there a way to prevent this.

```
# text in which variables for formula are stored

mainEffectText ="age sex bmi cohort"
interactionText="age*cohort"

# get text into R

mainEffects <- read.table(textConnection(mainEffectText))
mainEffects <- t(mainEffects)
mainEffects <- as.character(mainEffects[,1])

interactions <- read.table(textConnection(interactionText))
interactions <- t(interactions)
interactions <- as.character(interactions[,1])


# put all terms into one vector
allTerms <- c(mainEffects,interactions)

# create formula
form <- as.formula(paste("Surv(time, event) ~ ",paste(allTerms, collapse=" +")))
```

This gives the following with spaces added to the interaction terms:

```
form
# Surv(time, event) ~ age + sex + bmi + cohort + age * cohort
```

Comment: Why are the spaces a problem?

Comment: Is it overly readable?

Comment: The spaces do not seem problematic with respect to running the regression. I am trying to improve my understanding of these aspect of R. I tried a number of things that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces are not really a problem but anyways try this:

```
# inputs
mainEffectText <- "age sex bmi cohort"
interactionText <- "age*cohort"
lhs <- "Surv(time, event)"

both <- paste(mainEffectText, interactionText)
paste0(gsub(" ", "", lhs), "~", gsub(" ", "+", both))
```

giving:

```
"Surv(time,event)~age+sex+bmi+cohort+age*cohort"
```

If the inputs are of this form (`lhs` is as above), then use:

```
# inputs
mainEffects <- c("age", "sex", "bmi", "cohort")
interactions <- "age*cohort"

both <- paste(paste(mainEffects, collapse = " "), 
              paste(interactions, collapse = " "))
paste0(gsub(" ", "", lhs), "~", gsub(" ", "+", both))
```

Comment: I've been getting your advice for years now. The space still appears once as.formula is used, right?

Comment: Yes, the spaces will appear if you convert it to a formula and print the formula.    If `s` is the string produced above and `fo <- as.formula(s)` then you can convert it back to a string:  `gsub(" ", "", format(fo))` to remove the spaces.